# Everytime I try to run my project on Eclipse it shows progress information Creating type hierarchy on and its takes so much time to run

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, hierarchy, developer-tools

Everytime I try to run my project on Eclipse it shows progress information Creating type hierarchy on  and its takes so much time to run please give me solution to stop this and run my project without waiting [progress information creating type heirarchy on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84afv.jpg)

Resolve my issue to wait for running my project